# Are header files considered as API´s?

Tags: c++

I'm having a hard time understanding what an API actually is and does. Lets say I have a main.cpp file and I create a aa.cpp and aa.h header with functions I use in my main file from aa. Would the header be considered an API? Would the functions I use in main.cpp that are implemented in aa.cpp be considered the API?

Comment: Re: "Im having a hard time understanding what an API actually is and does." Welcome to the club. "API" has become a sloppy term for "something outside my code that I might want to deal with", that is, it's not a particularly useful term in casual discussions.

Answer (score 1):

An API is an interface which defines ***how*** to interact with a certain object. hpp files are not interfaces, but may contain such interfaces.

You can see any public part of a class as an API - which is the interface visible to all users to use in order to interact with a certain object.
The same goes for static functions, which allow functionality when there is no object involved.

Notice that not all the methods of a class are public; All the functions that are responsible for the internal representation of the object should not be visible to others, and *are not part of its API* (The principle of ***Encapsulation***).

Moreover, many times we use *abstract interfaces* (classes that usually have a name that starts with an I, such as *IClassName*). These interfaces are meant to be used as an abstraction of the underlining implementation, and are very big part of object-oriented programming (The principle of ***Abstraction***, which with ***Inheritance*** allows us to use ***Polymorphism***).

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of definitions for APIs. On of them is this :

**API provides an abstraction and functional specification.**
In C++, this is done by one or several header (.h) files, plus files supporting documentation (API documentation in .pdf).

So now when API is in header file (.h) what is it's content ?
Mostly API defines classes with their functions prototypes and member variables.

Where **function prototype** is just signature or declaration of function which tells compiler : name of the function, return type of function, accessibility of function (mostly public because it is API) and argument/parameter list.

**function prototype** doesn't contains body of function because it's signature/declaration of function.

Actual implementation of functions are written in different files (mostly .cpp files).

Now when definition is inside of header file (.h) and implementation is in .cpp file, we include content of header files into file which implements actual functionality of our API (so compiler can link those declarations inside of header files to functions which implements them). This is done by using **#include** directive inside of file which implements an API (.cpp file).

Than we can compile .cpp file into translation unit of different type e.g. object file (.o), library (Windows .lib, .dll ; Linux .a, .so) or executable program (.exe).

For demonstration of API in this answer you can image compilation of .cpp file into .lib file (static library).

Now you have .lib file which contains content of API (.h file) included into .cpp, but it is translated into binary format so it is not readable.

Now you upload your library and header file (which contains API) somewhere so people can download it.
When people download your header file and library they will use header file (API) by including header file to their own .cpp files. Now people can use functions which you defined in API because its implementation is in .lib file.

Result is that included header file is providing an **abstraction** in form of names of classes and functions which header file contains. They see and use only definitions - signatures (which are later linked by their compiler to implementation in .lib files) but they do not see full implementation which is inside of .lib file. That is point when an abstraction is created (When detailed functionality is hidden and only essential information is exposed).

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-160) is complete documentation for building simple math library where you will create simple API by creating class which contains definitions of simple math functions inside of header file.

Answer (score 0):

API stands for **A**pplications **P**rogramming **I**nterface (obviously), and ohh well, it is a broad term in the sense that it usually has a different interpretation based on the context of discussion, programming language, software design etc.

However, in all cases an API serves one purpose: to provide an interface of programming tools that ease the development of applications on top of it. A good API is one that captures the requirements of a certain domain and provides an abstraction layer of them in the form of data-structures, algorithms, etc.

An API can be header-only, e.g. think about the unit-test framework [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2), or it can be a combination of header and source files, e.g. the [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest) framework. The decision of which approach to follow is a design choice with advantages and disadvantages. It is true that header-only APIs are easier to integrate into another application.

@Kerek gave a good answer of what an API is in the context of Object Oriented Programming, where the interaction usually is associated with an object. This is usually a preferred design choice for Game-Development APIs.

To add on top of @Kerek's answer, an API may be implemented to ease Data Oriented Designs. For example, Nvidia provides CUDA libraries to ease the development of (accelerated) scientific computing applications. CUDA libraries (e.g. [cuFFT](https://developer.nvidia.com/cufft), [cuBLAS](https://developer.nvidia.com/cublas), [cuSOLVER](https://developer.nvidia.com/cusolver) etc.) are APIs in the sense that they provide routines for math-operations, math-algorithms, etc.

Another category of APIs are directive-based. Think about [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/), which is an interface of directives that makes easier the development of parallel thread-based applications.

**Long-story short-story:** an API is an interface of tools that makes easier the development of higher-level applications that are developed on top of. They make a distinction between which part of the code is intended for the API-users and which for the API-developers, and ideally, provide a documentation to describe the functionality they provide without diving into implementation details. An API can be header-only, but not necessarily.